# Bootstrap height container with long text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I downloaded Bootstrap template from: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/scrolling-nav/

```
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Scrolling Nav</h1>
                <div class="page-scroll">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#about">Click me!</a>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p>This demo is the same sort of scrolling navigation menu we use in our <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/grayscale.php">Grayscale theme</a>. Whenever you want to use the page scrolling feature, make sure the link points to an ID (<code>#about</code> for example), and that the parent of the link has the class <code>.page-scroll</code>. See how the button above and the menu bar links are formatted for a working example.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="about" class="about-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>About Section</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="services" class="services-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Services Section</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

If the content of the About Section is too long it's overlap on the Services Section, so I have a part of the About section on the Services Sections.

Services section : contains a form where the client can send me information, but since the About Section Overlap, some of the text of the About are on the Form of Services

I added Important! but it didn't work, any help please

Comment: I use the default page in : http://startbootstrap.com/templates/scrolling-nav/ but I added more than 50 lines of text and the text is dynamique. it may change.

Comment: I am thinking it has something to do with your div tags not being closed properly that is why I asked for your link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove css `height:100%` in the `scrolling-nav.css` in all three sections.

That will fix the bug

Comment: :p yes , and it was more more satisfying with less code writing , I dont know why didn't you accept it :p 
Anyhow , glad to help

Comment: xe4me, I applied your suggestion after all, since as you said it<s less code, I have to accept your answer Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are two ways of doing this

1) Add this class at the at the end in scrolling-nav.css

```
.about-section {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

or go to line no 36 in scrolling-nav.css and update height: 100%; with height: auto;

```
.about-section {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

you can also update .contact-section and .services-section like this to fix this issue completely.